# Execute facebook like in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have a "love" button on my site. When a user clicks this button, it's recorded in my database. As an extra, I also want this "love" to be seen as a "facebook like", so it appears on the user's facebook page. Is there a way to do a "facebook like" using javascript, with the instruction not coming from the normal ugly facebook button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called [likejacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likejacking) and may go against Facebook's terms of service.  The only legit way for a user to like your page is to use Facebook's "ugly" like button.  You could size your "love" button to be the same size and absolute position it over top of the Facebook like button which is what likejackers do. Then you could subscribe to the '[edge.create](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)' and then call back to your server to record it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I would like to know this as well. As an alternative - you could request extended permissions `publish_stream` then post to their wall with all the cool info including Image, Link, Title, Description, etc. I know this is not a 100% answer to your question, but I hope it helps gives a positive alternative.